# How to deal with: App Store Connect Operation Error (ERROR ITMS-90744: "Unsupported Xcode or SDK Version.)

Tags: ios, xcode, beta, itunes-store

I am trying to upload my build to iTunes connect, but from this morning I see this error:

*ERROR ITMS-90744: "Unsupported Xcode or SDK Version. Your app was built with a version of Xcode or SDK that is not yet supported for upload to App Store Connect. For more information about supported versions of Xcode and SDK for Testflight or App Store submissions, view the App Store Connect What's New page (https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/)."*

I have the latest beta MacOS 11 (Big Sur), and latest Xcode Version 12.0 beta 3 (12A8169g)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kml56.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. The solution was to upgrade to Xcode 12 Beta 4. According to Apple's News and Updates, Xcode 12 Beta 4 is supported: https://developer.apple.com/news/releases/?id=08042020g

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload apps to the App Store that were built using beta versions of Xcode or target beta versions of iOS.  You will need to build it with Xcode 11 targeting iOS 13 (or earlier).

EDIT: I think you can upload beta versions to Test Flight, if Apple has allowed it, but sometimes when new beta versions are released they don't allow it right away.  You may just have to wait a day or two in that case.